# Does the inverse of each element of a sample from a random variable constitute a sample from the inverse of that variable?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, sampling

Imagine you have a sample of $n$ elements from a random variable $X$. If I take the inverse of every element in that sample, is it always the case that the resulting set of numbers constitute a sample from $\frac{1}{X}$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, yes. What is the source of confusion? Any example, contradiction, ...?

Comment: Yes, more generally, if $x_i, \ i=1...n$ are sample of $X$, the $f(x_i)$ are samples of RV $Y:=f(X)$ by definition of a deterinistic function of a RV $X$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
The inverses remain independent.
The rest of it is just thinking through what exactly it means for a random variable to have the distribution of the random variable $\frac{1}X$.

Comment: Hello,

thanks for your answer.

I don't understand what you mean when you say "The inverses remain independent". Independent of what?

Comment: It was not stated exactly in the question, but where it says the original sample of $n$ elements of the random variable $X$, it is understood that these are a random sample.  That means they are all independent one from another. The inverses are also independent from each other.

Comment: Oh, now I understand.Thank you very much